# How exactly are physically unclonable functions used in authenticaton if they are unclonable?

Tags: authentication

There is ongoing and quite promising research with prototypes presented about using [physically unclonable functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_unclonable_function) (PUFs) in authentication. If they are practically unclonable, how is a PUF-based device authenticated?

Comment: [. . . the hardware analog of a one-way function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_unclonable_function)  One way/Trap door functions have a clear role in authentication; the wikipedia page explains the rest.

Comment: If you can't clone it, what will you compare it with?

Comment: There are different kinds. For some it's impractical to extract all information, but practical to extract *some* information. For another kind it's easy to read everything, but hard to manufacture a physical copy.

Answer (score 1):

**If they are practically unclonable, how is a PUF-based device authenticated?**

Consider the example of a smart-card chip, assuming that it has a puf-based circuit. If reliable enough then this chip will produce a unique key for a given challenge.

Even if an adversary attempts to replicate the same circuit with the same response the output key will be different provided. As [process variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_variation_(semiconductor)) is naturally occurring variation,when integrated circuits are fabricated. Due to process variation, each transistor parameters follows a gaussian distribution with a specific variance. With better fabrication process, this variance can be reduced but can't be neglected completely. So as long as process variation is there different puf-circuit will produce the unique key, provided they meet certain [puf-standards](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/657.pdf).